# vector of vector push back

Tags: c++, vector

I initialized a vector of vector of int. The sizes of inner vectors are arbitrary.
I read related questions but still cannot solve my problem.

```
vector<vector<int> > vec;
vector<int> get(int i) {
  return vec[i];
}

int main() {
  vec.resize(5);  // Only the first dimension has the fixed size
  get(2).push_back(2);  // If I do vec[2].push_back(2), it will work
  get(1).push_back(34);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cout << vec[i].size() << endl;  // output: 0
    for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); ++j) {
       cout << vec[i][j] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

I think things go wrong when I use get() method. But I cannot see where the problem is.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to state your problem is solved, mark the answer that helped you most as accepted. That's the usual action taken in Stack Overflow. Anyways, if you think all are equally good, you don't need to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `get` function is returning a copy of your vector, not the actual vector. You can do several things:

1. Get a pointer to the internal with this `vector<int> * get(..` and derefernce it (**This is very bad do not do this**
2. Return a reference to your vector `vector<int> &get(..` (**Better but still**)
3. Just use your `vector` straight up, the function get adds no benefit, and vector already has an `at` command (as well as `operator []`).

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/jmIWcW)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually simplified my code. The actual vec is private in my real code so I am adding an accessor to it. I will return a reference though as suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You want to return a reference to the vector, not a copy.

Change

```
vector<int> get(int i) {
  return vec[i];
}
```

to

```
vector<int>& get(int i) {
  return vec[i];
}
```

In order to return a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you return a copy from get, not the actual instance you want to address.

Change your code to

```
vector<int>& get(int i) {
        // ^
    return vec[i];
}
```

Comment: Dam it, every time ... just beat me.

Comment: Bah. You both beat me. Don't hear me whining. Nope. No whining at all. *SOB!*

Comment: @Ben From my tablet, seriously? Wow I'm getting better and better using it ;-)